# Why does my seed script for Laravel 4 generate improper insert queries?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-5.4, seeding

I have started working with Laravel 4 and am stumped by a weird issue. I wrote my migrations for the table, which successfully creates the table.

```
<?php    
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOrgRoles extends Migration {
    protected $tableName ;

function __construct(){
    $this->tableName = "org_roles";
}
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists($this->tableName);
        Schema::create($this->tableName, function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('role_name')->unique();
            $table->mediumText('role_description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down(){
        Schema::drop($this->tableName);
    }
}
```

Then I proceeded to write a simple model for the table as OrgRole.php

```
<?php

class OrgRole extends Eloquent {
  protected $tableName;
    protected $fillable = ['role_name', 'role_description'];

  function __construct(){
    $this->tableName = 'org_roles';
  }
}
```

Then I wrote the seed for the file as below

```
<?php

class OrgRolesTableSeeder extends Seeder {

  protected $tableName;

  function __construct(){
    $this->tableName = "org_roles";
  }

  public function run() {
    $defaultRoles = array(
      [
      'role_name'            =>    'guest',
      'role_description'     =>    'the most basic one of all'
      ]
    );

    foreach ( $defaultRoles as $role ) {
      OrgRole::create( $role );
    }
  }

}
```

Now when I run the seed command, the insert query formed is wrong, and the seeding fails

```
» php artisan db:seed                                                                                        
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'role_name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `or  
  g_roles` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2014-09-21 01:57:14, 2014-09-21 01:57:14))                   

  [PDOException]                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'role_name' doesn't have a default value
```

Can somebody help me understand what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the contructors from your seeder and model files. It's unnecessary in the seeder, since you call the model `OrgRole` in the `run()` method.
2. In the model file, replace the `protected $tableName;` with
   `protected $table = 'org_roles';`.

Then try running `php artisan db:seed` again. (Make sure you remove any records that were already seeded, or else the unique requirement on `role_name` will cause the seeding to fail.)

Comment: that worked.. So I was using the constructor to set the table name from a Constants Class. Why does the constructor interfere in this case ?

Comment: Because your constructor in `OrgRole`, which extends the `Eloquent` class, is overriding Eloquent's (the parent) constructor. If you include a constructor in `OrgRole`, regardless of what that constructor does, you would need to include `parent::__construct` so that the `Eloquent` constructor gets called as well. Also, note that the correct variable is `$table`, not `$tableName`.

Comment: Another bonus: in your `OrgRole` model class, you don't even need to include an explicit `$table` declaration at all, since you have named your db file `org_roles`. Laravel will automatically figure out the table name from your model name, assuming [a] your table name is the plural of your model name, and [b] capital letters within your model name correspond to an underscore in your table name.